# How can I loop through all $_POST indexes, but exclude a few indexes?

Tags: php, loops, post, foreach

my code:

```
$msg = "sky";

foreach($_POST as $item){
       if (empty($item)) {$msg = "sea";}
};
echo $msg;
```

It works, but I need to exclude some of the `$_POST` indexes from the above loop.

Something like below (Pseudo code):

```
foreach($_POST as $item).not("$_POST['a'], $_POST['b']") {...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do it like a whitelist where you only go through the indexes which you want e.g.

```
$whitelist = ["a", "b", "c"];
$msg = "sky";

foreach($whitelist  as $v) {
    if (empty($_POST[$v])) {$msg = "sea";}
}

echo $msg;
```

Or do it like a blacklist where you check that the index is not in a certain array e.g.

```
$blacklist = ["a", "b"];
$msg = "sky";

foreach($_POST as $v) {
    if (!in_array($v, $blacklist) && empty($v)) {$msg = "sea";}
}

echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unset the values that to be excluded,

```
$msg = "sky";
unset($_POST["a"]);
unset($_POST["b"]);
foreach($_POST as $item){
       if (empty($item)) {$msg = "sea";}
};
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Sajan, can I later set the values again?

Comment: Yes, or just copy $_POST values to new array and unset in new array

Comment: No OP can't access the indexes, if he unset 'ed it! He would have to do a copy into another array first.